# threejs - move 2 spheres created with 2 calls of a single function

Tags: three.js

i am a total beginner in threejs but:
i have a function

```
    function createSphere(
  sphere_name,
  radius,
  wSegments,
  hSegments,
  surface_map,
  xPos,
  yPos,
  zPos
) {
  // START ---- 

  let geometry1 = new THREE.SphereGeometry(radius, wSegments, hSegments);
  let material1 = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ map: surface_map });
  center = new THREE.Mesh(geometry1, material1);
  center.position.x = xPos;
  center.position.y = yPos;
  center.position.z = zPos;

  let materialsToMap = 1;

  for (let i = 10; i < 630; i += 62.8) {
    for (let k = 70; k < 215; k += 45) {
      let j = i / 100;
      let l = k / 100;
      let geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(radius, 16, 16, j, 0.62, l, 0.44);
      let material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
        map: materiale[materialsToMap],
        transparent: true,
        opacity: 0.8,
      });
      mesh_felii = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
      mesh_felii.position.x = center.position.x;
      mesh_felii.position.y = center.position.y;
      mesh_felii.position.z = center.position.z;
      mesh_felii.userData = linkuri[materialeDeAratat];
      mesh_felii.layers.set(1);
      scene.add(mesh_felii);
      materialeDeAratat++;
      if (materialeDeAratat >= materiale.length) materialeDeAratat = 1;
    }
  }
  //FINISH ----- aici am creat fasiile
  scene.add(center);
}
```

i call it 2 times in my script with different x coordinates so i get 2 spheres with a distance between them. Now i want to move one of the spheres to a new point in the scene using a slider. so i read the slider value and add it to center.position.x

how do i tell my script which one of the spheres i want to move? i found no way of identifying between the 2 spheres that were created. right now it only moves the sphere that was added by the second time i called the function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand the intention is to have `center` as the "parent" object containing the nested sphere layers/"slices".

If that's the case bare in mind both `center` and `mesh_felii` are added to the scene. Perhaps the intention was to nest each new `mesh_felii` instance into `center` so when `center` changes position so do `mesh_felii` ?

Also your function doesn't return anything at the moment. You could easily change that so it returns `center`. Once you store each new `center` in a separate variable you should be able to move them indepenedently.

(The `sphere_name` argument isn't used, but that's a minor detail)

I would suggest something along these lines:

```
function createSphere(
  sphere_name,
  radius,
  wSegments,
  hSegments,
  surface_map,
  xPos,
  yPos,
  zPos
) {
  // START ---- 

  let geometry1 = new THREE.SphereGeometry(radius, wSegments, hSegments);
  let material1 = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ map: surface_map });
  let center = new THREE.Mesh(geometry1, material1);
  center.position.x = xPos;
  center.position.y = yPos;
  center.position.z = zPos;
  // seteaza nume (util pt. cautari)
  center.name = sphere_name;

  let materialsToMap = 1;

  for (let i = 10; i < 630; i += 62.8) {
    for (let k = 70; k < 215; k += 45) {
      let j = i / 100;
      let l = k / 100;
      let geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(radius, 16, 16, j, 0.62, l, 0.44);
      let material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
        map: materiale[materialsToMap],
        transparent: true,
        opacity: 0.8,
      });
      let mesh_felii = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
      mesh_felii.position.x = center.position.x;
      mesh_felii.position.y = center.position.y;
      mesh_felii.position.z = center.position.z;
      mesh_felii.userData = linkuri[materialeDeAratat];
      mesh_felii.layers.set(1);
      center.add(mesh_felii);
      materialeDeAratat++;
      if (materialeDeAratat >= materiale.length) materialeDeAratat = 1;
    }
  }
  //FINISH ----- aici am creat fasiile
  scene.add(center);
  // returneaza sfera center (pivot-ul feliilor)
  return center;
}

// test
let sphere1 = createSphere("sphere1", 10, 16, 16, yourSurfaceMapInstance, 0, 0, 0);
let sphere2 = createSphere("sphere2", 10, 16, 16, yourSurfaceMapInstance, 0, 0, 0);
// move spheres
sphere1.position.x = -15;
sphere2.position.x =  15;
```

Bare in mind this function relies on a few global variables and there are some variables that seem to have a similar function:

- `materialsToMap` is used as an array index
- `materialeDeAratat` is also used as an array index, but it is also being incremented and reset to 1 while `materialsToMap` isn't.

The nested sphere structure reminds me a bit of the [clipping intersection example](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_clipping_intersection).

Comment: I did try creating variables that equal the functions but have not tried returning center. That seems like a good ideea. I'll try it as soon as I reach my pc and get back to you. Thanx

Comment: In the snippet you posted it looks like `center` is a global variable which points to a new instance each time `createSphere` is called and since originally it didn't return a value, the only way to set the position was via the `xPos, yPos, zPos` arguments. Give that a go and feel free to post an update to your question with your attempt. Bafta!

Comment: Cu placere! Spor :) !